# Advertisement upload admin module implementation using AdSence

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, adsense

I want to make available the UI for my site administrator to upload the advertisements for the site. I just come across the Google adsence concept for the same. so can i build this using adsence API and how ? I mean i need the sample P O C so that move a head with considerations. i am new in adsence totally. i didn't heard about it so far. so want to understand its capabilities also.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have multiple pages to display the same data, so potentially different Views, you can take into account [MVP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx) / [MVC](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/MVC_intro12122005162329PM/MVC_intro.aspx) patterns. So main purpose is to separate View from undelying logic and data itself.

Also take a look at the [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc), perhaps you can build your web application using this framework.

> ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic
>   websites that enables a clean separation of concerns and that gives
>   you full control over markup for enjoyable, agile development. ASP.NET
>   MVC includes many features that enable fast, TDD-friendly development
>   for creating sophisticated applications that use the latest web
>   standards

Comment: Ok , can you please eloborate how can i develope advertiesment upload module / design using MVC ?